# C# TimeSpan exceeds 23:59:59

Tags: c#, timespan

I'm working on a small application to read XML file and display value on a grid. Certain types of values to display are `TimeSpan`.

It works well until the "TimeSpan currentTime" below does not exceeds 23:59:59. For instance, If XML data `description.Attributes.GetNamedItem("time").Value` is equal to 25:05:00 I get a `TimeSpan` equal to  25.00:05:00. Thus not 25hours and  5 minutes BUT 25 days and 5 minutes !

Does someone can help me ?

```
TimeSpan currentTime;
if (!TimeSpan.TryParse(description.Attributes.GetNamedItem("time").Value, out currentTime))
{
    // alert parse is not good
    return;
}
```

Comment: 1) Does the same thing happen if you invoke the three-arguments form of `TryParse()` and specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in the second argument? 2) Are you sure your XML contains `25:05:00` and not `25.05:00`?

Comment: the Timepan class stores millis, seconds, minutes, hours and days (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). What you got there seems like a parsing problem. Can you post the string (/ an example string) you're parsing there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the class interprets the timespan you give as incorrect for a period of time (and thus it reverts to days instead of hours).

It should be in this format for 25 hours:

```
1:01:05:00
```

Or this (which is the preferred one):

```
1.01:05:00
```

Comment: Don't you mean `1.01:05:00` ? (dot instead of colon)